# Problem while updating the gridview in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview 'GridViewMcm" with dropdownlists while editing in first and second columns and textboxes in next two columns. PairId is the Primary Key of the table.

Following is the code for Onrowupdating event.

```
SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(con);
mySQLconnection.Open(); 
DropDownList drdList1, drdlist2;
drdList1 = (DropDownList)(GridViewMcm.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("ddeditfrom"));
drdlist2 = (DropDownList)(GridViewMcm.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("ddeditto"));
TextBox txtrate, txtdesc;
txtrate = (TextBox)(GridViewMcm.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txteditrate"));
txtdesc = (TextBox)(GridViewMcm.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txteditdesc"));
SqlCommand strupdate = new SqlCommand("Update mcmtable set Measure1FromSymbol = @Measure1FromSymbol, Measure2ToSymbol = @Measure2ToSymbol, ConversionRate = @ConversionRate, ConversionDesc = @ConversionDesc Where MeasurePairId=@PairId", mySQLconnection);
strupdate.Parameters.Add("@Measure1FromSymbol", SqlDbType.Text).Value = drdList1.SelectedValue;
strupdate.Parameters.Add("@Measure2ToSymbol", SqlDbType.Text).Value = drdlist2.SelectedValue;
strupdate.Parameters.Add("@ConversionRate", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = decimal.Parse(txtrate.Text);
strupdate.Parameters.Add("@ConversionDesc", SqlDbType.Text).Value = txtdesc.Text;
strupdate.Parameters.Add("@PairId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewMcm.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());
strupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
GridViewMcm.EditIndex = -1;
```

Here is the error which am getting while executing the above code:

> "Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'U_mcmtable''. Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object 'mcmtable'. The
>   statement has been terminated."

I found the problem to be that the dropdownlist values 'drdlist1.SelectedValue' and 'drdlist2.SelectedValue' are not able to fetch the selectedvalue in the dropdownlist but fetching some default value. And as the default values which they are fetching are already present in the table as a combination in a particular row, it is throwing the error. Is there any mistake in the code part above??

Comment: Suggestion one: "Can ne1 help me in solving dis?" is not English. Don't use that sort of language if you want to be taken seriously.

Comment: okay. thanks for informing. new to this sort of help websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the data that you are attempting to insert/update in the affected table(s). Verify that the data you are attempting to insert/update does not already exist in the table that could cause the UNIQUE KEY constraint to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Check the U_mcmtable constraint in the database. My guess is that the constraint is set for the from and to fields and that you're trying to update to a conversion combination that's already in the table.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is that the drdList1 and drdList2 are not getting populated with the SelectedValue but are populating with some Default value. Is there a mistake in my code? Can you help me with this too.?

Answer (score 0):

That Error Denotes That you are trying To insert duplicate value in the column name [Name]
A Unique Constraint Has Been Set on that column Which means The values In that column
Should Be unique

You can get the list of all constraints on your mcmtable table by

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where Table_Name='mcmtable'
```